# Counting the no. of words in a csv file in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, csv

I am trying to count the no. of dates stores in the first line of a CSV file (Separated by commas):- 
State,Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,1/25/20,1/26/20
I have to count the no. of dates after Long(i.e. output  = 5).
I have written the code to read the CSV file, which I have shown below, but, how shall I count the no. of dates after long. Would highly appreciate your help. Please feel free to ask for any other piece of information. Thanks.

```
char** readCSV(const char* csvFileName, int& csvLineCount)
{
    ifstream fin(csvFileName);
    if (!fin)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    csvLineCount = 0;
    char line[1024];
    while(fin.getline(line, 1024))
    {
        csvLineCount++;
    };
    char **lines = new char*[csvLineCount];
    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    for (int i=0; i<csvLineCount; i++)
    {
        fin.getline(line, 1024);
        lines[i] = new char[strlen(line)+1];
        strcpy(lines[i], line);
    };
    fin.close();
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Are you beholden to using `char**` or can you use `std::vector<std::string>`? Regardless, it looks like you can just count the number of commas per line and subtract 3.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I was actually gonna use that approach, but how shall I check for the no. of commas? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnFilleau I was using strcmp() to compare each word in a line with ',', but it was giving me an error

Comment: `strcmp` compares two c-strings. You want to count the number of a particular character in a c-string. This is easier with `std::string`, since we can grab iterators easily. For a c-string you can use std::count from <algorithm>: `std::count(line, line + std::strlen(line), ',');` This takes advantage of the compatibility between pointers and iterators: you can treat a pointer to an array as an iterator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thanks a lot for the help highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are reading a record that contains one or more subrecords.
I recommend using a `Date` class as well as a `Record` class.

```
class Date
{
  public:
    unsigned int month_num;
    unsigned int day_num;
    unsigned int year_num;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Date& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Date& d)
{
    char forward_slash;
    input >> d.month_num;  input >> forward_slash;
    input >> d.day_num;    input >> forward_slash;
    input >> d.year_num;
    return input;
}
```

Overloading `operator>>` for the `Date` class will come in handy later.

Now the record class:

```
class Record
{
  public:
    std::string    state;
    std::string    region;
    std::string    latitude;
    std::string    longitude;
    // A container for the date subrecords
    std::vector<Date> dates;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
     std::string text_line;
     std::getline(input, text_line);
     std::istringstream record_stream(text_line);
     std::getline(record_stream, r.state, ',');
     std::getline(record_stream, r.region, ',');
     std::getline(record_stream, r.latitude, ',');
     std::getline(record_stream, r.longitude, ',');
     Date d;
     while (record_stream >> d)
     {
         r.dates.push_back(d);
         char comma;
         record_stream >> comma;
     }
     return input;
}
```

The above function reads a text line of input, since the records are terminated by a newline.  A stream is created from the text line.  The stream helps in reading a variable quantity of dates.

**Edit 1: Reading in the file**
Your input code would look something like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (fin >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

Yes, you *can* use C-Strings and arrays, but C++ streams and `std::vector` simplify the code and simple code has less defects than complicated code.

Also, the `std::vector` and `std::string` classes manage dynamic memory for you.  They expand as necessary.  No need for checking for array overflows.  They are also easier to pass.  Passing arrays requires passing the capacity also (and maybe the quantity of elements in the array).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Highly Appreciate it!